# How to display the last record from a manyToMany relationship in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have multiple images in my uploads table with related to vehicle_id, as foreign key like this,

```
uploads table
id          fileName        vehicle_id
1            1.jpg               1
2            2.jpg               1
3            3.jpg               1
4            4.jpg               1
5            28.png              2
6            28.png              2
7            29.png              2
8            30.png              3
9            31.png              3
10           56.png              3
```

The vehicle table have many to many relationship with the image table and data grap using eager loader in VehicleController,

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::with('uploads')->get();
        return view('vechicles.index')->withVehicles($vehicles);
```

Now these images are showing in the vehicles/index.blade.php file

```
 @foreach($vehicle->uploads as $upload)

         <tr>
                        <td><a href="{{route('vechicles.show',$vehicle->id)}}"><img src="/images/{{ $upload->resized_name }}"></a></td>

                    </tr>

        @endforeach
```

My problem is occurred now, in this way, I can show all images in the table whith related to proper **vehicle_id** but, I need only show one image (to matching **vehicle_id**) like thumbnail to above line. Then how can I configure this? actually I need only one image to print in index.blade.php to related in each vehicle_id,
as an example here are 4 images with related to vehicle_id 1. but I need only print decending oder one image to print and same to vehicle_id 2 and etc.... how can do this?

**Updated User Model**

```
class Upload extends Model
{
    public function vehicle()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Vehicle::class);
    }
}
```

**updated Vehicle Model**

```
 class Vehicle {
    public function thumbnail() {
        return $this->hasOne(Upload::class)->orderByDesc('id');
    }
}

$vehicles = Vehicle::with('thumbnail')->get();
```

**current Blade file**

```
 @if($vehicles)
@foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
{{$vehicle->district}}
{{$vehicle->town}}
{{$vehicle->brand}}
{{$vehicle->model}}

<hr>

 <tr>
  @foreach($vehicle->thumbnail as $aaa)
                    <img src="/images/{{ $aaa->resized_name }}">
                    @endforeach

                </tr>


@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Please post the `uploads` relationship.

Comment: Please see My updated User Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jonas Staudenmeier solution is the cleanest. However, if you cannot for any reason update the model, you can use this in any of your blade template.

*app/Http/Controllers/VehiculeController.php*

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Vehicule;

    class VehiculeController extends Controller {
        public function index() {
            $vehicules = Vehicule::with('uploads')->get();

            return view('vehicule.index')->withVehicules($vehicules);
        }
    }
?>
```

*resources/views/vehicule/index.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            @forelse( $vehicules as $vehicule )
                <td>
                    @if( $vehicule->uploads->count() > 0 )
                        <a href="{{ route('vehicules.show', $vehicule->id) }}">
                            @php
                                $upload = $vehicule->uploads->sortByDesc('id')->first();
                            @endphp
                            <img src="{{ $upload->resized_name }}" alt="{{ $upload->fileName }}" />
                        </a>    
                    @else
                        This vehicule does not have any images attached.
                    @endif
                </td>
            @empty
                <td>No vehicules to display.</td>
            @endforelse
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here we use Laravel Collection `->first()` method to get the first method, but do not forget (this is done in the example) to check if there is any uploads (or any relationship in a general manner) when you get the first element.

When you fetch relations of a model, all [Laravel Collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods) are available until you use a finisher (`first`, `all`, ...).

Comment: occured this error **Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\Banda\Desktop\acxian\resources\views\vechicles\index.blade.php)**

Comment: Check if your field in the uploads table matche the property Iwrote in this example: `fileName`, `resized_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [latest](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) method in relationship to get the latest model.

```
class Vehicle {
    public function thumbnail() {
        return $this->hasOne(Upload::class)->latest();
    }
}
```

Comment: in your **public function thumbnail()** what is the meaning of **thumbnail** is it model?

Comment: Please check what you uploaded

Comment: acording to my knowlage it shold be model?

Comment: `thumbnail` method will return the last inserted `Upload` model